# Insert data into a google spreadsheet via a link

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way for users to send data from an email sent to them in a single click using google scripts.

Basically, I have a spreadsheet with a list of emails, and I want to send an email to all of them (I've already set up a sort of mail merge script).

The tricky part is that I want the emails to contain links unique to each person. If they click one of the links, I want data to be entered into the spreadsheet in the row corresponding to their email address.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just deploy your script as a webapp and have the link point to it. Their row number or email address can be specified as a parameter to your app, that can do the required operation and show them a message that "It's done". You'll have to do some coding though, this will not happen by a simple magical flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328073/2013981) to basically the same question a few weeks ago. It uses the technique described by Henrique in the above comment to use an item from the individual row as a parameter in the webapp url.