# Writing data to a cell in Google Sheets from a 3rd party link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I make a link that adds data to a Google Sheet?

I am working on a student calling system that allows the following:
1-Parents arrive at our school's entrance and show a QR Code
2-The QR Code is a link that specifies their child's name, year, etc.
3-That data is then sent to a Google Sheet that is being displayed in our assembly hall so the student knows their parent has arrived

It seems like this should work, but I'm missing something:
[Allowing for third party updates to Google Spreadsheets via email response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319254/allowing-for-third-party-updates-to-google-spreadsheets-via-email-response/23328073#23328073)

I understand (and can do) how to write a Script and publish as a WebApp, and even to add parameters to that WebApp that are passed as variables, but how do I choose which Google Sheet document to add the data to?

Since this is still conceptual, I don't have any examples, but would greatly appreciate some guidance. I have a decent understanding of coding/scripts, but I'm no expert.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `but how do I choose which Google Sheet document to add the data to?`, when I saw [the script shown in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328073), the Spreadsheet ID is set using the query parameter. Isn't this situation what you want? And, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Why do you wish to use emails since you are in the same school and the network is available.  The network is much more secure than any email.

Comment: @Tanaike - The way I understand the script/Google Sheet in the example, there is a Script that is published as a WebApp. This script passes an additional parameter (in this case 'status' to a second Google Sheet and writes that parameter to the specified cell. In the example, I don't see where the first Script links to the second Google Sheet. Do I need to use the 'id' parameter to add in the Google Sheet URL? Sorry if I'm asking a basic question - I know I'm missing something.

Comment: @Cooper - I do not want to use the email part of the example. I am trying to find a way for parents to have their child's name card (with a QR code) scanned at our school's entrance) which will then trigger their name to display on our auditorium's screen. There is not email involved.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I was trying to write the Google Sheet WebApp in a seperate document, but I have now added it to the same document. Here is what I did:

In a Google Sheet - Go to Extensions - Apps Scripts

Use the following code in Code.gs:

```
function doGet(request) {
  Logger.log(request);
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var user = request.parameters.id;
  var year = request.parameters.year;
  for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == user[0]){
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 3,1,1).setValue(year[0]);
    }
  }
  var result = "Congratulations! You just said '" + year[0] + "' to " + user + ".";

  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  cell.setValue(year);
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,2);
  cell.setValue(user);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}
```

Then Deploy - New Development - Choose WebApp

Copy the WebApp URL and add ?id=John&year=9 to the end like this:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfymany numbercj/exec?id=John&year=9

Put that into a QR code generator and when that code is scanned, the name appears in the Google Sheet document.

When I looked at the original example, it appeared that two Google Sheet documents were being used, so I couldn't see the link between the two. In fact the scpript that becomes a WebApp is attached to the same Google Sheets document.

Thanks again for the responses.